# How to show $F_1/F_2$ is bounded?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

> If $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ are homogenous polynomials of degree $n$ and
>   $m$ respectively, then the function $f$ is defined as
>   $f(x,y)=\frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x,y)}$ [when $Q(x,y)\neq 0$] and 0 [when
>   $Q(x,y)=0$]. This type of a function will be continuous at $(0,0)$ if
>   $n>m$.

I was thinking of proving it using $P(x,y)=x^nF_1(y/x)$ and $P(x,y)=x^mF_2(y/x)$ and writing $f(x,y)$ as $x^{n-m}(F_1/F_2)$. If $F_1$ by $F_2$ is bounded then we can say that the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ since the double limit $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ exists there. Or perhaps even using polar coordinates might be useful. Any hints how to show $F_1/F_2$ is bounded?

Answer (score 2):

The original statement is not true. For $P=x^2$ and $Q=y$ we get $P(t,t^3)/Q(t,t^3)=1/t,$ which is unbounded as $t\to 0.$ This example gives $F_1=1$ and $F_2=y/x,$ and $F_1/F_2=x/y$ unbounded near zero.